# Get Text Color from Range

Tags: c#, excel, com, add-in

I'm writing an excel add-in in C# and among other things I need to get the textcolor (in RGB if possible) of a cell.

Range does have a [Font.Color](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.font.color%28v=office.14%29.aspx) property, but that's just a single double which I've no idea how to convert to a rgb representation - actually no idea what it represents (horrible documentation for the whole stuff I'm afraid, or maybe I'm looking in the wrong place)

Can't seem to find any examples for this on the web, only examples of how to set the color, but using the `ColorTranslator.FromOle` (instead of ToOle) doesn't work since that expects an int..

Comment: have you tried the macro recorder?

Comment: @Mitch How would that help me? Doesn't that just allow me to record some action and then replay it?

Comment: it also allows you to inspect it and see the code generated....

Comment: @Mitch Interesting and good to know, but how would I get it to tell me how to *read* the textcolor? Obviously recording a macro that sets the color is simple, but no idea how to do it the other way round. The color setting part is the same as usual: `Selection.Font.Color = <someVal>` (strangely it's set to an int, but if I try to read it in C# the value is a double?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well there we go, a bit closer inspection of the values shows that the double of `Font.Color` actually just stores the integer RGB values.

Which works fine because a IEEE-754 double can store all integers smaller than 2**53 exactly so we don't have any problems with rounding for any RGBA values. Still seems like a strange bug to me, no idea how that happened.

Answer (score 2):

I modified [this code](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/exceldev/thread/df8a1e1e-e974-4a9c-938a-da18ae9f5252/) slightly to get:

```
Sub test()
    Dim Col As Long
    Dim R As Long, G As Long, B As Long
    Col = ActiveCell.Font.Color

    R = Col Mod 256
    G = (Col \ 256) Mod 256
    B = (Col \ 256 \ 256) Mod 256
    Debug.Print R
    Debug.Print G
    Debug.Print B
End Sub
```

Here's some interesting reading from [Chip Pearson](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/colors.aspx).

Comment: I forgot to mention that this is VBA, not C#, but you could probably tell that :).

Comment: Yeah was obvious ;) The problem is that `Font.Color` is a double in C# which doesn't make any sense. If it was an int, yeah it'd be obvious, but what the hell am I supposed to do with a double? Hmm although maybe just using the bitpattern representation or casting could work, let's see.